# Missing trophies in Assassin's Creed Brotherhood

Tags: ps3, achievements, assassins-creed-brotherhood

I almost completed AC:B but the game suddenly stopped tracking trophies. For example, I just discovered the shrine in Saint Peter's Basilica (which should unlock the *Amen* trophy) and nothing happened.

What's even more frustrating, though, is that I wasn't awarded with any of the other trophies that are unlocked by completing the main storyline (e.g. completing Sequence 8).

Is there anything I can do to make my game load the missing trophies without having to restart it from the beginning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, delete the Assassins Creed Brotherhood in GAME DATA UTILITY. Then load up the game, if it says update then say no. After the game has loaded up, quit it. Then load it up again, this time say yes to update and hopefully, trophies should pop up.

REMEMBER DO NOT DELETE THE AC B IN SAVE DATA UTILITY. DELETE IT IN GAME DATA UTILITY (TOP OF GAME SECTION ON XMB).

Comment: Thanks, that worked and it re-started giving me trophies. Unfortunately, it did not award me with the original trophies (e.g. Amen), so I guess I'd need to replay the game (and I'm not willing to do that...)